# SQLite3Stmt::execute() expects exactly 0 parameters, 1 given Error?

Tags: php, sqlite, authentication, parameters

I am getting the following error when trying to run the following PHP file:

SQLite3Stmt::execute() expects exactly 0 parameters, 1 given ( Line 34 )

and

Call to undefined method SQLite3Stmt::fetch() ( Line 36 )

```
 <!doctype html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Untitled Document</title>
 </head>

 <?php
 class MyDB extends SQLite3
  {
  function __construct()
  {
     $this->open('Users.db');
  }
  }

  $db = new MyDB();


 $email_address = $_POST['email_address'];
 $password = $_POST['password'];

 $email_address =($email_address);
 $password =($password);

 $email_address = intval($_POST["email_address"]);
 $password = intval($_POST["password"]);
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE email_address='$email_address' AND 
 password='$password WHERE email_address=? AND where password=?'";


 $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
 $stmt->bindParam(1, $email_address);
 $stmt->bindParam(2, $password);

 $result = $stmt->execute($sql);

 while($column = $stmt->fetch())
 {
 echo $column["email_address"];
 echo $column["password"];
 };


if($email_address==1){
  echo "<h1>Logged In</h1>";
 }; 

  ?>


 <body>
</body>
</html>
```

This is meant to be a simple Log in page which connects to a SQLite database which then returns if logged in or not.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is pretty straight forward. You're supplying a parameter to the execute method when it doesn't need one.

```
$stmt->execute();
```